# How can I get access to ValidationMessageFor from an extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, extension-methods

How can I get access to the HTML extensions ...For like LabelFor, EditorFor, ValidationMessageFor

I'm writing my own extension like that

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Mvc.Html
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Text

Public Module HtmlExtensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function Asistente(Of TModel As Class)(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, model As TModel) As MvcHtmlString
        helper.ValidationMessage("Home") 'It works fine
        helper.ValidationMessagefor()    'It show the next message 'ValidationMessagefor' is not a member of 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper     
    End Function

...
```

Actually it's because I want to produce a mvcHtmlString like that

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Numero)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Numero)
    **@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Numero)**
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ValidationMessageFor` method requires a generic type html helper. So your method should probably look something like this:

```
Public Shared Function Asistente(Of TModel, TProperty)(helper As HtmlHelper(Of TModel), expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty))) As HtmlString
    Return helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression)
End Function
```

This will allow you to use that extension for any model and your call wouldn't change. I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking though.

```
**@Html.Asistente(Function(model) model.Numero)**
```

(note that vb was produced using a c# to vb converter - but it looks right)

If you want to use the first sample you posted then you're going to have to write it something like this:

```
Public Shared Function Test(Of T As User)(helper As HtmlHelper(Of T), model As T) As HtmlString
    Return helper.ValidationMessageFor(Function(f) f.Name)
End Function
```

However, that's a specific use case because if you don't force the model type to a specific type then you won't get the lambda expression properties to show up and thus won't compile.